# Silverlight - Reading path data at runtime

Tags: silverlight, xaml, path, runtime

I have a work area (grid) where I add and remove objects at runtime, mostly canvases or stackpanels containing different paths.

When I have dragged 'n' dropped all objects I want to my 'drawing', I want to save the data to the database.

I use XamlWriter.Save() to get the string data and it works "fine", but all Path Data is empty:
***XAML for Path Data is not available due to Silverlight runtime limitations***

```
<Path StrokeThickness="0.98">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry>
        <!-- XAML for Path Data is not available due to Silverlight runtime limitations -->
      </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Stroke>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF000000">
        <SolidColorBrush.Transform>
          <MatrixTransform>
            <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
              <Matrix />
            </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
          </MatrixTransform>
        </SolidColorBrush.Transform>
        <SolidColorBrush.RelativeTransform>
          <MatrixTransform>
            <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
              <Matrix />
            </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
          </MatrixTransform>
        </SolidColorBrush.RelativeTransform>
      </SolidColorBrush>
    </Path.Stroke>
  </Path>
```

Is there any way around this?
I really need to get the path data to be able to save and then later open and continue working on my 'drawing'.

Help and/or other ideas are very welcome..!

Thanks in advance!

//Anna

Comment: XamlWriter does not come with Silverlight - where did you get your implementation of this class?  Have you tried this one: http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/? It claims to work properly with path geometries as of Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0):

If RobSiklos' comment doesn't help, you might have to either serialize that data in another way, or manually post process the XML and add the path data yourself.